# On mousemove translate Carousel with smooth animation

Tags: jquery, html, animation, mousemove, smoothing

Hi all :) I need to do carousel with some effect like this.

http://discoveroutpost.com/

I know that i need to use and modify the `translate3d(x,y,z)`css propriety but i don't know how make the animation smooth different between image and external div. >_<

```js
var mousePointer = document.getElementById('test')

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  var x = e.pageX / window.innerHeight;
      x = x * -60;
  mousePointer.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(' + x + '%)';
  mousePointer.style.transform = 'translateX(' + x + '%)';
})
```

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```